# sqlite3 won't work second time

Tags: c++, sqlite

My Sqlite connector works just fine the first time I try to insert rows, but after it is closed and I run the program again it won't work at all.

Here is my constructor

```
  Sqldatabase::Sqldatabase() {
  open_connection("Database.db");

  sqlite3_stmt *statement;
  std::string sql = "SELECT id FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
  char *query = &sql[0];
  if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &statement, 0) == SQLITE_OK && sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
    article_counter = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0) + 1;
  } else {
    article_counter = 1;
  }
}
```

Here is my preparedStatement method.

```
bool Sqldatabase::prepareStatement(std::string sql) {
  char *query = &sql[0];
  sqlite3_stmt *statement;
  int result;

  if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, sql.size(), &statement, 0) == SQLITE_OK) {
    result = sqlite3_step(statement);
    std::cout << sql << '\n';
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    if(result == SQLITE_DONE) {
       return true;
     }
  }
  std::cout << "SQL failed: " << sql << '\n';
  return false;
}
```

And finally here is where I call the method.

```
bool Sqldatabase::create_ART(int ng_id, std::string title, std::string author, std::string text) {
  //Creating article
  std::ostringstream s;
  s << "INSERT INTO articles (id, title, author, content, created) " <<
       "VALUES (" << article_counter << ", '" << title << "', '" << author << "', '" << text << "' , CURRENT_DATE)";
  std::string sql(s.str());
  prepareStatement(sql);

  //Adding article to newsgroup
  std::ostringstream t;
  t << "INSERT INTO contains VALUES ( " << article_counter << " ,  " << ng_id << ")";
  std::string sql2(t.str());
  article_counter++;
  return prepareStatement(sql2);
}
```

My test script looks like this. And I already have a Newsgroup with id 1 in the database.

```
Sqldatabase db;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    std::cout << "-----Test of Memdatabase, Newsgroup and Article classes-----" << std::endl;
    db = Sqldatabase();

    db.create_ART(1, "Happy day", "John", "Sunday afternoon is pretty chill");
    db.create_ART(1, "Chill day", "Peter", "Sunday afternoon is pretty chill");

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, you're trying to create a new record with the same id. ids are typically unique. try:

```
db.create_ART(2, "Chill day", "Peter", "Sunday afternoon is pretty chill");
```

Comment: One of the hazards of copy-paste programming.

Comment: I thought so too first, but that id is the id of which newsgroup the article is suppost to be inserted into. The first INSERT statement doesn't use the ng_id at all :/   All SQL statements seem to fail (update, delete, insert), but select statements are work still.

Comment: Ok, are you're sure the DB isn't enforcing unique entries in the id column?

Comment: It is, but even different id´s do not work either strangely. The two lines for create_ART are creating two new articles in the newsgroup 1. article_counter is keeping track of the article id on it's own.